# Gettting FIREBASE WARNING: transaction at [my-path] failed: disconnect starting today

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-compute-engine, firebase-admin

I have a program that works well for years. It has not changed perry much in the last months.

Starting this morning, I started receiving this errors:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: transaction at [my-path] failed: disconnect

It happens when I use transactions. And it only happens when running on all on my 4 Google Compute Engine VMs.

On another VM (Linode) it works and locally it works.

Somebody else also have this issue, but he is using Google App Engine:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/wU7xYQ13UvM

I wrote the Firebase Support team and there`s their answer:

> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for bearing with me.
>
> If the issue is not reproducible in your local environment, apologies as I may > not be able to help you on this. Troubleshooting or debugging issues with non-> Firebase product is beyond the area of my expertise as Firebase support, as well > as it is outside of the scope of this channel. With that being said, you may consider to reach out directly into the "Google Cloud VM" support channel, or into the community channels, such as Stack Overflow, Quora, and discussion forums, to help you gather suggestions regarding your use case. Members of the developer community as well as the Firebase team are active participants and may be able to provide guidance.
>
> Should you have any other Firebase-related questions or clarifications, don't hesitate to reach out to us again.
>
> Regards,

So here I am...

I really need help, this issue is going on for many hours now and my services are degraded.

EDIT:
Here`s the code that fails. The transaction returns an error.

```
function processShapshot(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    function checkMessageStatus(innerSnapshot: DataSnapshot, currentData) {
        if (currentData) {
            if (!currentData.id) {
                currentData.id = innerSnapshot.key;
            }
            if (!currentData.date) {
                currentData.date = moment().format();
            }
            if (!currentData.status) {
                currentData.status = 'pending';
                return currentData;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    const messageStatus = snapshot.ref;

    messageStatus.transaction(checkMessageStatus.bind(null, snapshot), (error, committed, transactionSnapshot) => {
        if (error) {
            logger.log('error in transaction', error);
            throw error;
        }
        if (committed) {
            // Do something
        }
    }, false);
}
```

I'm using the Admin SDK version 5.12.1 in general, but I have one customer that uses 5.12.0 and one other that uses the OLD firebase 2.4.1 SDK. But they all behave the same.

It started at 2018-07-04T12:55:12.840Z on server A

It started at 2018-07-04T12:14:52.610Z on server B

It started at 2018-07-04T12:34:50.816Z on server C

It started at 2018-07-04T12:08:11.714Z on server D

Here`s the stack trace:

> 2018-07-04T12:08:11.717Z 16718 'error in transaction' Error: disconnect
>       at Repo.rerunTransactionQueue_ (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14758:67)
>       at Repo.rerunTransactions_ (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14665:10)
>       at Object.onComplete (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14645:19)
>       at PersistentConnection.cancelSentTransactions_ (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12279:25)
>       at PersistentConnection.onRealtimeDisconnect_ (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12149:14)
>       at Connection.close (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11544:22)
>       at Connection.onConnectionLost_ (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11509:14)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onDisconnect (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11220:23)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onClosed_ (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10933:22)
>       at Client.mySock.onerror (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10796:19)
>       at Client.dispatchEvent (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api/event_target.js:22:30)
>       at Client._emitError (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api.js:158:10)
>       at TLSSocket. (/my-app-path/node_modules/@firebase/database/node_modules/faye-websocket/lib/faye/websocket/api.js:127:12)
>       at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)

EDIT:
The guy that had the same problem with App engine just told me that he moved his stuff away from US-EAST1 and it seams that the problem is gone.

I can't move my VMs as easilly as he could move his App Engine stuff.

EDIT:
Here`s a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hs4g7xwb/1/

I just runned this on an instance on us-east1 region and after 5-10 transactions it fails.

By enabling the admin.database.enableLogging(true) option, I can see this:

> [2018-07-04T22:27:25.629Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":12,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.678Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.678Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 Network error: wss://[my-firebase-url]/.ws?v=5: read ECONNRESET
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.678Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 WebSocket is closing itself
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.679Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Realtime connection lost.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.679Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Closing realtime connection.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.679Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Shutting down all connections
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.679Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: data client disconnected
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.679Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Trying to reconnect in 0ms
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.680Z]  @firebase/database: 0: onDisconnectEvents
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.681Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.681Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Making a connection attempt
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.682Z]  @firebase/database: getToken() completed. Creating connection.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.682Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Connection created
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.682Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Websocket connecting to wss://s-usc1c-nss-250.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ls=[string-removed]&ns=[my-firebase-project]
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.897Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Websocket connected.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.898Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Realtime connection established.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.898Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: connection ready
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.899Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: {"r":13,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"[string-removed]"}}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.899Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Listen on /messages/noop for {"ep":null,"i":"status","l":50,"sp":null,"vf":"l"}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.899Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: {"r":14,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/messages/noop","q":{"sp":null,"ep":null,"l":50,"vf":"l","i":"status"},"t":1,"h":""}}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.971Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":13,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1530746845}}}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.972Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Primary connection is healthy.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.972Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":14,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:25.972Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: listen response {"s":"ok","d":{}}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.383Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: handleServerMessage d {"p":"messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp","d":{"date":"2018-07-04T22:27:36.791Z","id":"-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp"},"t":1}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.384Z]  @firebase/database: event: /messages/noop:child_added:{"date":"2018-07-04T22:27:36.791Z","id":"-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp"}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.385Z]  @firebase/database: 0: transaction on /messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.385Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Listen called for /messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp default
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.386Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Listen on /messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp for default
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.387Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: {"r":15,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp","h":"eV7iJC9FSjQ3Nm2HseXG+4auWEM="}}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.388Z]  @firebase/database: event: /messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp:value:{"date":"2018-07-04T22:27:36.791Z","id":"-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp"}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.388Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: {"r":16,"a":"p","b":{"p":"/messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp","d":{"date":"2018-07-04T22:27:36.791Z","id":"-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp","status":"pending"},"h":"eV7iJC9FSjQ3Nm2HseXG+4
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.433Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.433Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Network error: wss://s-usc1c-nss-250.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ls=[string-removed]&ns=[my-firebase-project]: read ECONNRESET
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.433Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 WebSocket is closing itself
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.433Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Realtime connection lost.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.433Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Closing realtime connection.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.433Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Shutting down all connections
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.433Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: data client disconnected
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.433Z]  @firebase/database: 0: transaction put response {"path":"/messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp","status":"disconnect"}
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.434Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: transaction at /messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp failed: disconnect
>   error in transaction Error: disconnect
>       at Repo.rerunTransactionQueue_ (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14758:67)
>       at Repo.rerunTransactions_ (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14665:10)
>       at Object.onComplete (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14645:19)
>       at PersistentConnection.cancelSentTransactions_ (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12279:25)
>       at PersistentConnection.onRealtimeDisconnect_ (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12149:14)
>       at Connection.close (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11544:22)
>       at Connection.onConnectionLost_ (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11509:14)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onDisconnect (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11220:23)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onClosed_ (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10933:22)
>       at Client.mySock.onerror (/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10796:19)
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.441Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Trying to reconnect in 0ms
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.441Z]  @firebase/database: 0: onDisconnectEvents
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.441Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.442Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Unlisten called for /messages/noop/-LGbP6J0WxrYY0KJKRPp default
>   [2018-07-04T22:27:36.442Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: disconnect

EDIT:
Ok I have more details... I removed the transaction thing and run the fiddle again with the logging enabled. I got a lot of network error also:

> [2018-07-04T22:41:31.272Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:2:0 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.272Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:2:0 Network error: wss://s-usc1c-nss-250.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ls=[string-removed]&ns=[project-name]: read ECONNRESET
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.272Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:2:0 WebSocket is closing itself
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.272Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:2: Realtime connection lost.
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.272Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:2: Closing realtime connection.
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.272Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:2: Shutting down all connections
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.272Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: data client disconnected
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.273Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Trying to reconnect in 0ms
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.273Z]  @firebase/database: 0: onDisconnectEvents
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.273Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:2:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.
>   [2018-07-04T22:41:31.273Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Making a connection attempt

But my program does not fails, the reconnection just do it`s job.

So it really seams to be a network issue between us-east1 and the Firebase databases.

Comment: You might want to say more about what you're doing here.  All you've given us is an error message.  What is the code that's failing?  Are you using the Firebase Admin SDK?  If so, what version?

Comment: I added a lot of new details... Seams to be a network issue between us-east1 and firebase servers

Answer (score 0):

After some emails with the Firebase supports, they admitted that it was a network failure on their side between the us-east1 zone and Firebase.

Here's their final answer:

> Hi Vincent,
>
> The issue has been resolved for all affected users as of Thursday, 2018-07-04 23:50 US/Pacific. Engineers were able to come up with a workaround in our networking stack to mitigate the issue and it should not recur. We're still investigating the root cause, but it may take couple of days to figure it out.
>
> I'm happy to hear your service is restored. Thank you again for your patience and help.